# How to get the div as tight as possible around large font size?

Tags: css

How do I get a div that fits tightly around very large text. The research I've collected shows that I should line-height? Are there other ways or is this how it's done?

```
<style>
    .rscls1 {
        background-color: brown;
        font-size:58rem;
        line-height: 45rem;
    }

    .rscls2 {
        font-size: 5rem;
        background-color: lawngreen;
        line-height: 5rem;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto rscls2">Speed Limit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto rscls1">55</div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `line-height` is the only way. When you get very tight, though, depending on the metrics of the particular font you are using, you may find that the glyphs are not vertically centered, so in that case you can add some top or bottom padding to improve the appearance.

When you run this snippet, you’ll see that in the first div with the brown background, the glyphs are closer to the bottom than the top. In the second div, with the blue background, bottom padding has been added and then the line height reduced to compensate, with the result that the glyphs are now vertically centered in the box.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
}
div {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.d1 {
  background-color: brown;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
.d2 {
  background-color: navy;
  line-height: 0.675;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">55</div>
<div class="d2">55</div>
```